# Wordpress post pagination continuous

Tags: shortcode, pagination, next-post-link, previous-post-link

I have these shortcodes which I am using as links in my front end to get the next post and previous post.

When I get to the last post it just keeps reloading the last post again. How can I get it to loop back to the first post?

```
function prev_shortcode($atts) {
    $prev_post = get_previous_post();
    $permalink = get_permalink($prev_post);
    return ($permalink);
}
add_shortcode( 'prev', 'prev_shortcode' );

function next_shortcode($atts) {
    $next_post = get_next_post();
    $permalink = get_permalink($next_post);
    return ($permalink);
}
add_shortcode( 'next', 'next_shortcode' );
```

Answer (score 1):

`get_next_post` returns `null` if there is no post anymore. And then `get_permalink` will have a null value for `$next_post`, so it will get the permalink for the current post, resulting in linking to the same post again and again.

You should thus check for `null`, and if so, link to the first (latest) post.
Something along the lines of (in your code style):

```
function next_shortcode( $atts ) {
    $next_post = get_next_post();
    if ( ! is_null($next_post) ) {
        return get_permalink( $next_post );
    }
    $posts = get_posts( 'numberposts=1' );
    return $posts[0];
}
```